# How to set up environment variables for development environment

Tags: configuration, development-environment

This [Twelve-Factor App](http://www.12factor.net/config) manifesto insists on putting configuration variables in the environment rather than in the code. I'm using [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/index.html) to daemonize server processes, which allows for adding environment variables in the configuration, but when I work on a particular server's code, I'll stop the Supervisord process and run the same command from the console in order to see the output conveniently.

If I move the configuration to environment variables from the code, how should I set up the development environment variables? Should I just have a Bash script to run before running the server process, or is there a better way?